# Валидация формы на jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите пожалуйста с валидацией формы на jQuery! Чтобы проверялось перед отправкой. При наведении на картинку появлялось окошечко об ошибке. :hover (css)
Совсем запустался! Новичком в этом деле! Сделал валидацию на проверку занятости логина в БД. Но нужно добавить еще для проверки пустоты, максимальной/мин длины символом, только англ и буквы, обязательное поле! Заранее спасибо!

HTML

```
<input type="textbox" name="login" id="register-textbox-login" class="register-textbox-login"  placeholder="Логин">
<div class="reg-valid-login" id="valid-icon"></div>
    <div class="error-1" id="error-1">
  <div class="error-1-text">Пользователь с таким логином уже существует</div>
  </div>
```

Скрипт

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#register-textbox-login").blur(function()
    {
        $.post("structur/check-login.php",{ login:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data == 'no')
          {
            $("#valid-icon").fadeTo(200,0);
            $("#error-1").fadeTo(200,1);            
          }
          else
          {
            $("#error-1").fadeTo(200,0);
            $("#valid-icon").fadeTo(200,1);
          } 
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php    

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('bodyshop');

 if(isset($_POST['login']))
   {
    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
    $result = mysql_query('select * from users where login="'.$login.'"');
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo "no";
} 
else
{
    echo "yes";
}
   }
      ?>
```

[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Comment: Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, исходный код текстом, а не изображениями.

Comment: Выложил кодом, как и просили!

Comment: **mysql_*** Внимание
Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.   http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php